# Moving solution to ASP.NET vNext - Unable to reference assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am in the process of moving an existing solution over to ASP.NET vNext. My solution is a traditional N-tier app. With that in mind, the solution has four projects. Those four projects are organized like this:

```
/backend
  /library
    Sample.cs
    project.json
  /web
    project.json
/test
  /library
    SampleTest.cs
    project.json
  /web
    project.json
global.json
```

In short, the `web` project references the `library` project. The `/test/library/` project is intended to test the `library` project. The `/test/web/` project is intended to test the `web` project.  My problem is, I cannot seem to reference the `library` project from my `test` project. If I attempt to reference a class in `library`, I get an error that says:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'library' or one of
 its dependencies. General Exception (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131500)
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'library' or one of
 its dependencies. General Exception (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131500)
File name: 'library' ---> Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn.RoslynCompilationEx
ception: C:\Projects\MySolution\test\library\SampleTest.cs(21,7
): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Sample' could not be found (
are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Here are the contents of my related files

**/backend/library/project.json**

```
{
  "version":"3.0.0.0",
  "description":"This is the app library",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "warningsAsErrors": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Data.Common":"0.1.0.0-alpha-build-0137"
  },
  "code": [ "**\\*.cs", "..\\Shared\\*.cs" ],
  "frameworks": {
    "net45": {}
  }
}
```

**/backend/library/Sample.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MySolution.Library
{
  public class Sample
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Save() 
    {
    }
  }
}
```

**/test/library/project.json**

```
{
  "commands": {
    "test": "Xunit.KRunner"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Xunit.KRunner": "1.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": { },
    "aspnetcore50": { }
  }
}
```

**/test/library/SampleTest.cs**

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Framework.Runtime;
using Xunit;

namespace MySolution.Library
{
  public class SampleTest
  {
    [Fact]
    public void Save()
    {
      Sample sample = new Sample();
      sample.Save();
      Assert.NotNull(sample);
    }
  }
}
```

**global.json**

```
{
  "sources": [ "backend/library" ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I seem to reference my `library` project from my `test` project?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In `global.json` change the `sources` to `["backend","test"]`
2. You are missing the `library` reference in the test project:

   ```
   "dependencies": {
       "library": "",
       "Xunit.KRunner": "1.0.0-beta1"
    },
   ```

Comment: If I add `library` to the `test\library\project.json' file, as shown in #2, I get an error. If I run `kpm restore`, the error I get is: `TODO: Circular dependency references not supported. Package 'library'.`. If I run the test, I get an error that says: `Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.`

Comment: Just to rule out some other issues, can you try to rename the test project to something else? Like `library.test`

Comment: bravo!. I renamed the `/test/library` directory to `test/library-tests` and it worked. It feels like a hack. However it works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It feels like a bug to me. I'll open one

Comment: Also, remember that NuGet packages are generated for each project so you don't want projects with the same name because you'll get conflicts